# Why isn't my JS code displaying the message to the HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom

Thanks for viewing my question!

I'm a Javascript newbie and I'm learning about retrieving user input values from HTML forms, and I can't figure out why my messages aren't displaying on the page. When I run the code in the browser, the error console tells me that there's a problem on line 16 of the .js file, where the .firstChild.nodeValue is returning null. Where can I fix the problem with the inheritance and receiving the value from the form?

By the way, I'm interested in keeping with the firstChild.nodeValue method instead of the .innerHTML method. :)

Here is the code in my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="X_3_1.js"></script>
    <title>Exercise 3-1 HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Exercise 3-1</h1>
    <form id="user_input" name="user_input" method="get">
        <p>
            <label for="first_name">Enter First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="first_name">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="children">Do you have children? :</label>
            <input type="text" id="children">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="age">If so, how old is your oldest child? :</label>
            <input type="text" id="age">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Submit Information" onClick="processInfo()"><br>
        </p>
        <span id="message"></span>
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code in my Javascript file:

```
function processInfo() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var children = document.getElementById("children").value.toUpperCase();
    var result = children.substring(0, 1);
    var age = parseInt(document.getElementById("age").value);

    var today = new Date();

    if (result === "Y" || children === "YES") {
        if (age <= 19) {
            document.getElementById("message").firstChild.nodeValue = "<p>You still have kids at home</p>";
        } else if (age > 19) {
            document.getElementById("message").firstChild.nodeValue = "<p>Hopefully they have moved out of the house</p>";
        }
    } else if (result === "N" || children === "NO") {
        document.getElementById("message").firstChild.nodeValue = "<p>It must be peaceful at home, " + firstName + " on this date of " + today.getMonth() + "/" + today.getDate() + "</p>";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("message").firstChild.nodeValue = "<p>Did you answer Yes or No?</p>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will more than likely have to use:

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = 'text';
```

as your message element doesn't have any children

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize it was such a dumb mistake! :P

Answer (score 2):

your `document.getElementById("message").firstChild.nodeValue` can't access the first child because `<span id="message"></span>` here doesn't have any first child.

```
console.log(document.getElementById("message").firstChild )
```

Above statement returns null.You can see it in your browser console.

use `document.getElementById('message').innerHTML="your text";` instead